# Is it possible to process two different files in the same Gzip file (.gz) using mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, gzip

I have two different files in one `.gz` file. I need to process these files and put it in two different locations using map reduce. What would be the best solution. Is it possible as I know that Hadoop outputs the entire data based on the number of reducers. But, I want the files to be processed based of the file type 1 and 2 which I mentioned above.

Comment: Umm, `gzip` doesn't support multiple files (it's a compressor and not an archiver) that's why it is so often combined with `tar`. Can you clarify how you've stored your files?

Comment: what about zip files. Could we use that.